# Qt - how to access QComboBox data inserted in QTreeWidget

Tags: qt, qt4

During runtime I have inserted QCombobox in my QTreeWidget like this:

```
    //global defines
    #define COLUMN_1 (0)
    #define COLUMN_2 (1)

    //Init QComboBox to QTreeWidget - works fine.
    QTreeWidgetItem *item = new QTreeWidgetItem(_myTreeWidget);
    item->setText(COLUMN_1,"testing");

    QComboBox *box = new QComboBox();

    box->addItem("select1");
    box->addItem("select2");
    box->addItem("select3");

    _myTreeWidget->setItemWidget(item, 1, box);
```

The above code works, but I also want to read the data text in these columns. Eg. get the strings "testing" & "select2" from code above. The problem is that I can't figure out how to read the "QComboBox::currentText()"  in the comboboxes.
I have tried:

```
   QTreeWidgetItemIterator it(_myTreeWidget);
   while(*it)
   {
      QTreeWidgetItem *item = *it;

      QVariant first   = item->text(COLUMN_1);
      QString firstStr = loggerName.toString();  //this works

      QComboBox *box    = (QComboBox*)item->data(COLUMN_2, 0);   
      QString boxValStr = box->text().toString();   //this doesn't works, always empty string

      //... more code to handle strings... 

      it++;
   }
```

Feels like the "item->data(COLUMN_2, 0)" is wrong way to go cause it returns a QVariant.
Solution on this problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Solved it thanks to the help from @Umnyobe and @Zaiborg above. Here is a total working example:

Init QTreeWidget with text in column1 and QComboBox in column2:

```
//global defines
#define COLUMN_1 (0)
#define COLUMN_2 (1)

QTreeWidgetItem *item = new QTreeWidgetItem(_myTreeWidgetPtr);//item to put in tree
item->setText(COLUMN_1,"animal");                             //item for column 1 in the tree.

QComboBox *box = new QComboBox();
box->addItem("mouse");                                        //adds selections for comboboxes
box->addItem("cat");
box->addItem("dog");

_myTreeWidgetPtr->setItemWidget(item, COLUMN_2, box);           //insert items in tree.
```

Read values from tree:

```
QTreeWidgetItemIterator it(_myTreeWidgetPtr);
while(*it)
{
    QTreeWidgetItem *item = *it;

    //Init pointer to current combobox
    QComboBox* box = qobject_cast<QComboBox*>(_myTreeWidgetPtr->itemWidget(item, COLUMN_2)); 

    //Get data from QTreeWidget
    QString col1Str = item->text(COLUMN_LOGGER);   
    QString col2Str = box->currentText();

    it++;
}
```

hope it can help someone :)

Answer (score 5):

`QComboBox *box    = (QComboBox*)item->data(COLUMN_2, 0);`
When I read this code, I went into panic mode. Look at the signature:

```
QVariant QTreeWidgetItem::data ( int column, int role ) const
```

As you used `setItemWidget`, you should probably use

```
QWidget * QTreeWidget::itemWidget ( QTreeWidgetItem * item, int column ) const
```

ps: If you want to cast, use C++ casts. Much better, use `qobject_cast<SubtypeofQObjectPtr>` for `QObject`. It returns null when the cast is invalid.

Indeed, I mean retrieve the combobox using a call similar to :

```
QComboBox* box = qobject_cast<QComboBox*>(treeWidget->itemWidget(item, column));
```

Comment: Thanks, but you dont mean you can ge the comboboxes currentText out of a qwidget?

Comment: @jaguzu simply cast it ... `QComboBox* box = qobject_cast<QComboBox>(treeWidget->itemWidget(item, column));`

Answer (score 0):

use the `QSignalMapper` class to collect the different boxes in the treewidget.

then connect the `QSignalMapper::mapped()` signal to some slot and use the combobox

edit:

```
QSignalMapper* mapper = new QSignalMapper(this);
QComboBox *box = new QComboBox();   
connect( box, SLOT(/*whatever*/), mapper, SLOT( map() ) );
mapper->setMapping( box );
myTreeWidget->setItemWidget(item, 1, comboBox);
```

Comment: Thanks! yes, i was thinking about saving pointers to the comboboxes, but hopped i could get access to them through the treewidget.

Comment: saving the pointers might be a 'easy' solution, but think about you refill the tree. the possibility that you have invalid pointers stored is just too high.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone who is looking for a Python solution, 
(PySide / PyQt QComboBox in QTreeWidget), here is it:

```
    item = QTreeWidgetItem(self.treeWidgetAnimals)
    item.setText(0, "animal")
    combo_box = QComboBox()
    combo_box.addItem('mouse')
    combo_box.addItem('cat')
    combo_box.addItem('dog')
    self.treeWidgetAnimals.setItemWidget(item, 1, combo_box)
```

I was looking for hours but no other forum like pass reference "parent" like a "delegation":

`item = QTreeWidgetItem (self.myTreeWidgetItemObject)`

if you do not pass the parent, error ir not returned but the ComboBox not appears in  display TreeWidget.